# Powershell append csv file after each while loop

Tags: powershell, csv

Can you please tell me how to add a csv file so that the data for each variable is written to the required column? for each new loop to a new line?

```
New-Item -Path . -Name "Test.csv" -ItemType "file" -force | Out-Null
("" | Select-Object Date, RAM_1, RAM_2, RAM_3, RAM_Used_total_%, RAM_Free%, CPU_Load% | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType -Delimiter ";")[0] | Out-File '.\Test.csv'

# Start the while loops

while($true) {

# In which data is collected into variables that need to be entered into each of the columns, respectively

$date
$RAM_1
$RAM_2
$RAM_3
$RAM_Usage
$Free_RAM
$CPU_Load

    
    
    Start-Sleep -s 60
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) - the trick is to create _objects_ (rather than individual variables) that have property names corresponding to the columns - the same way you currently create an empty object with `Select-Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to manually write the CSV file - let `Export-CSV` take care of that for you instead:

```
while($true) {
  # populate your variables ...
  $date = $(<# ... #>)
  $RAM_1 = $(<# ... #>)
  $RAM_2 = $(<# ... #>)
  $RAM_3 = $(<# ... #>)
  $RAM_Usage = $(<# ... #>)
  $Free_RAM = $(<# ... #>)
  $CPU_Load = $(<# ... #>)

  # then create a new object with the correct column names
  $record = [pscustomobject]@{
    'Date'              = $date
    'RAM_1'             = $RAM_1
    'RAM_2'             = $RAM_2
    'RAM_3'             = $RAM_3
    'RAM_Used_total_%'  = $RAM_Usage
    'RAM_Free%'         = $Free_RAM
    'CPU_Load%'         = $CPU_Load
  }

  # append record to CSV
  $record |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -Append

  Start-Sleep -s 60
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already wrote something to the file before calling `Export-Csv` - don't do that! If you want to use `;` as the delimiter, change to `$record |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -Append -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Mathias, Thank you a lot! You made my day!

Comment: @Irina_008 You're most welcome! Please consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left :)